# code: -32003, message: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value, data: None

Tags: forge, anvil

Anybody getting this error message when running `forge script`?

```
{"logs":[],"gas_used":36453,"returns":{}}

SKIPPING ON CHAIN SIMULATION.
Sending transactions [0 - 0].

Transactions saved to: [TRUNCATED]/run-latest.json

Sensitive values saved to: [TRUNCATED]/run-latest.json

Error: 
Failed to send transaction

Context:
Error #0: Failed to estimate gas for tx: 0xa6588218af3b69925349825ca9eaa3fb6bf07cabf8c3d5bb1d7c21112e9ea5c2
Error #1: (code: -32003, message: Insufficient funds for gas * price + value, data: None)
```

The forge script command I'm running is:

`forge script V2Test.s.sol --sig 'run(bytes memory)' $input --sender $SENDER --skip-simulation --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:1234 --broadcast --unlocked --legacy --with-gas-price 35243602672 --json --priority-gas-price 1099305329 -vvv`

Where:

$input is an EIP1559Request

$SENDER is 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 (One of the accounts provided from running anvil fork)

The RPC URL comes from my anvil fork command, basically forking the mainnet and listens on port 1234. What I am not understanding is, the error complains about having insufficient funds and the JSON log output states gas_used as 36453, but anvil forked accounts have 10000 ETH on creation, and I can verify it having balance still when running:

$ cast balance 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 --rpc-url http://127.0.0.1:1234
9999949831288618906569

Simulating the transaction works, e.g. running the `forge script` command without the `--broadcast` flag; however, I'm trying to get this transaction broadcasted on my forked net. I have tried adding  and removing additional flags on my `forge script` command but no joy.

Comment: Leaving this here for others. Fixed with help from Foundry devs.
You can turn on extra debugging using `export RUST_LOG=node,api,rpc,backend=trace` and that showed me the account `forge` was using to perform the transaction, which was `0x3078616330393734626563333961313765333662` and its the prefix for the cheatcode that I was using in my run function in my script.
In short, make sure this below is correct in your run function.

uint256 deployerPrivateKey = uint256(YOUR PRIVATE KEY);

vm.startBroadcast(deployerPrivateKey);

More info in https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/7456